# Dependency for retrofit not loading. Build failure

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I am new to Android(just recently started). I added the following to dependecies to the `build.gradle` file of my app:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'  
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

The build fails and I get the following error message:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2.
>        Required by:
>            MedicalRecordTrackingSystem:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/retrofit2/retrofit/2.0.2/retrofit-2.0.2.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/retrofit2/retrofit/2.0.2/retrofit-2.0.2.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2.
>        Required by:
>            MedicalRecordTrackingSystem:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2.

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like your gradle cannot resolve the repository could u please post full gradle files (both of them - app and project)

Answer (score 0):

Use only this dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```